# How to get heap dump from Tomcat, which is running as a windows service?

Tags: tomcat, windows-services, heap-dump

I have a situation where everyday I got to restart my Tomcat server for running the J2EE-Struts application. The version used is JDK6 and Tomcat6. I believe so that taking heap dump from the Tomcat server helps out in analyzing the memory leaks and performance.

Now the challenging part is that the Tomcat is running as a windows service and I have to achieve from this case. I don't prefer using any tools for the same.

Please advise on how to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Windows service is documented by Tomcat, you should read that first. Generating a heap dump on-demand is possible through [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) , of course you need to configure JMX settings in your Tomcat.